# Remove <div> wrapper from wp_nav_menu output

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to remove the  wrapper from the wp_nav_menu() function.

I've passed container => false to the arguements array and added a hook in my functions.php, but it still shows the  wrapper.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args )
{
    $args['menu'] = false;
    $args['menu_class'] = false;
    $args['container'] = false;
    $args['container_class'] = false;
    $args['show_home'] = true;

    return $args;
}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7):

Reading the codex: [Function Reference/wp nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Removing_the_Navigation_Container)

You may need to set the Theme Location in your functions.php file and then assign your menu to it?

This is what is says in the codex:

> In order to remove navigation container, theme location specified in
>   functions.php and used among arguments in function wp_nav_menu ( eg.
>   'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) must have a menu assigned to it
>   in administration! Othervise argument 'container' => 'false' is
>   ignored.

If you need to register a location you can use the following:

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'Your_Theme' ),
) );
```

Then pass it in the `wp_nav_menu()` function

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false ) );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I have passed null to container and menu is not wrapped in div tag.

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array('menu' => 'Bočni',
        'container' => null
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the boolean data type it's not available for this Parameters, please read this [Function Reference/wp nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

So the best way to remove this div wrapper replace it with ul, like this example

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu' => 'header-nav_menu',
  'theme_location'    => 'header-nav_menu',
  'container'         => 'ul', //To replace div wrapper with ul 
  'menu_class'        => 'YOUR CLASS'//Add classes to your ul
 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container' => '',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'theme_location' => 'footer-1',
));
```

An existing menu have to be associated to your location ('footer-1' in my example), otherwise, there is always a div wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `"container" => false` doesn't work, It only works when you write
`"items_wrap" => "%3$s"`  but it removes all wraps including `<ul>` if you want to remove `<div>` and have your menu wrapped in `<ul>` I recommend to do this way

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'  => 'header_menu',
    'menu'            => 'header_menu',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
    'container'       => false,
    'menu_class'      => 'nav',
    'list_item_class' => 'nav-item',
    'link_class'      => 'nav-link',
    'menu_id' => 'menu-main-menu'
));
```